# Qual è il significato di "sbandata" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> L’amico di Rocco era stato un prete davvero. Si chiamava John Palmieri. L’avevano cacciato dalla Madre Chiesa perché a forza di frequentare i cinesi del quartiere con lo scopo di convertirli alla vera religione, si era preso una **sbandata** furibonda per l’eroina. Quando aveva cominciato a derubare i parrocchiani per comprarsi la polvere, era stato costretto a lasciare l’abito.

Sapreste spiegarmi il senso del vocabolo "sbandata" in questo brano? L'ho cercato in parecchi dizionari, ma le accezioni che ho trovato non sembrano avere molto senso nel contesto di questo brano.

Answer (score 2):

Prendo la definizione dal [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sbandata/):

> In senso fig., avvenimento, atteggiamento, azione o altro che
>   costituisce una deviazione improvvisa e vistosa dal comportamento
>   abituale: *la sua è solo una s.; fare una s. in politica; prendere una
>   s. per qualcuno*, innamorarsene in modo improvviso e violento, deviando
>   rispetto al proprio abituale comportamento.

In questo caso significa appunto che il personaggio (un prete) aveva preso a drogarsi (con l'eroina) e questo era diventato per lui un'ossessione, al punto da arrivare a derubare i parrocchiani pur di soddisfare la sua brama per la droga.

Comment: Quindi, il significato sarebbe che, in certo modo, si era "innamorato" dell'eroina?

Comment: Che si era lasciato andare a comportamenti riprovevoli, quale l’uso della cocaina.

Answer (score 2):

Si riferisce al senso figurato del verbo ***[sbandare](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/sbandare.shtml):***

> [sban-dà-re] v.intr. (aus. avere) [sogg-v]:
>
> - 1 Detto di veicoli stradali e mezzi di trasporto navali e aerei, deviare improvvisamente e accidentalmente dal normale assetto di marcia
> - ***2 fig***. Allontanarsi dalla linea di comportamento ritenuta giusta

Nota l’espressione molto comune:

***[Prendersi una sbandata](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/sbandata.shtml):***

> 2 fig. *Improvviso e intenso innamoramento:*  prendersi una sbandata  per qlcu.; - *disorientamento morale o politico*: dopo la sbandata ha lasciato il movimento.

(Sabatini Coletti)

Il sacerdote in questo caso per qualche motivo cede al vizio della droga e quindi “sbanda” ossia inizia un percorso diverso, deplorevole e pericoloso, quello dell’uso dell'eroina con tutte le conseguenze del caso.

Comment: Quindi, il significato sarebbe che, in certo modo, si era "innamorato" dell'eroina?

Comment: Quindi, "prendersi una sbandata per l'eroina" è da intendersi come sbandarsi nel senso figurato che hai spiegato a causa dell'eroina?